# Spring Integration - exponential retry with CircuitBreakerAdvice

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I want to implement exponential retry with CircuitBreakerAdvice:

Can I increase halfOpenAfter exponentially? For example:  it tries  for threshold(3), first it waits for 15 seconds, then later it tries again for threshold, halfOpenAfter for 30 seconds, then later it tries again for threshold, halfOpenAfter for 60 seconds, then later it tries again for threshold, now (finally) file has to move to an error folder. This has to happen for all the files in the source folder.

Tried below code, but not sure how to make it exponential and how to move the file to error folder. This code is getting into infinity loop, forever it keeps trying.

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="sourcedirectorypath"
                                      prevent-duplicates="false" auto-startup="true"
                                      id="fileInbound" channel="sftpChannel">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000" error-channel=""/>
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="sftpChannel"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="sftpChannel" output-channel="outsftpChannel"
                           expression="@dsf.setThreadKey(#root, headers['file_name'])"/>

    <int:channel id="outsftpChannel"/>

    <int-sftp:outbound-gateway id="sftpOutboundAdapter" session-factory="dsf" command="put"
                               request-channel="outsftpChannel" charset="UTF-8" chmod="774" reply-channel="replyChannel"
                               remote-directory-expression="@sftpConfig.getRemoteDirectory(headers['file_name'])">

        <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice" id="handlerAdvice">
                <property name="failureChannel" ref="sftpFailureChannel"/>
            </bean>
        </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>

    </int-sftp:outbound-gateway>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="sftpFailureChannel" expression="@sftpConfig.failed(#root)">
        <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <bean id="circuitBreakerAdvice"
                  class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice">
                <property name="threshold" value="3"/>            <!-- close after 3 failures -->
                <property name="halfOpenAfter" value="15000"/>        <!-- half open after 15 seconds -->
            </bean>
        </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int:service-activator>

    <int:channel id="replyChannel"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="replyChannel" output-channel="nullChannel"
                           expression="@dsf.clearThreadKey(#root, headers['file_name'])" requires-reply="true"/>
```

Please correct me if my ask is wrong, but i need exactly as below. We can implement with resilience4j + spring boot, but i need it with Spring Integration.

```
resilience4j:
      retry:
        instances:
          intervalFunctionExponentialExample:
            maxRetryAttempts: 3
            waitDuration: 15s
            enableExponentialBackoff: true
            exponentialBackoffMultiplier: 5
```

after 3 attempts of 15s, 75s, 375s exponentially it should go to fallbackMethod - "moveFileToErrorDirectory"

Answer (score 0):

The `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice` doesn't not support an exponential `halfOpenAfter`. At the moment. You can use a combination of this one and a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`, where this one goes as a first in the advice chain.

What you show about `resilience4j` is really a retry configuration, not a circuit breaker. So, think about that one more time if just a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` is enough for you. The `ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer` might be used as a fallback. The point of Spring Integration is really sending messages not calling methods.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain